# Hovering 2 table cells simultaneously, 4 fields apart from each other in both directions

Tags: javascript, html, css

My table looks like so:

[image]

I wrote a bit of CSS so when I hover on a specific field under a 15-year mortgage column, the corresponding cell under the 30-year mortgage is also hovered.

```
td:hover, td:hover + td + td + td + td {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

This works great when I select a 15-year mortgage field, but not when I select a 30-year mortgage field. That is, it doesn't work in the other direction.

[image]

The table structure is pretty straightforward:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colSpan='1' />
        <th colSpan='4'>15 year</th>
        <th colSpan='4'>30 year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colSpan='1' />
        <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
        <th>Investment Payment</th>
        <th>Loan Amount</th>
        <th>Investment Amount</th>
        <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
        <th>Investment Payment</th>
        <th>Loan Amount</th>
        <th>Investment Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Year x</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
        <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</tbody>
```

I've already read that there is [no "previous sibling" selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) so I am looking for a different solution. JavaScript solutions are fine if pure CSS can't get the job done.

Comment: Do you want a css, html solution only or a javascript solution is fine too?

Comment: javascript is totally fine @Manish. I'm actually trying to work on a javascript solution while I wait on responses here. I'll add the js tag to the post.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work because the hovering is +4 td (`td + td + td + td`) if there's 45-year mortgage and you select 30-year mortgage, it will hovered there. the solution is close onto using -4 td

Comment: @jgozal cool. Please see my answer. have posted two solutions one with javascript only and other one with jQuery which ever suits you best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a javascript only solution. You can use classes and the `classList` and then `add` and `remove` functions. With jQuery this can be simplified even more. Here i have made an assumptions that it will always be the 4th column which is similar. To make it more generic you can tweak the code accordingly..

**JavaScript Only Solution**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  tdElems = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
  tdElems = Array.prototype.slice.call(tdElems);

  tdElems.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function($event) {
      tdElems.forEach((td) => {
        td.style.background = 'white';
      })
    });
    elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function($event) {
      showHover($event.target);
    });
  })
}



function showHover(elem) {
  parent = elem.parentElement;
  for (i = 0; i < parent.children.length; i++) {
    if (parent.children[i] === elem) {
      elem.style.background = 'lightgray';
      if (parent.children[i + 4]) {
        parent.children[i + 4].style.background = 'lightgray';
      } else if (parent.children[i - 4]) {
        parent.children[i - 4].style.background = 'lightgray';
      }
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colSpan='1' />
      <th colSpan='4'>15 year</th>
      <th colSpan='4'>30 year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colSpan='1' />
      <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
      <th>Investment Payment</th>
      <th>Loan Amount</th>
      <th>Investment Amount</th>
      <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
      <th>Investment Payment</th>
      <th>Loan Amount</th>
      <th>Investment Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Year x</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year x</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Solution with jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').hover(function($event) {
    $('td').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    const parent = this.parentElement;
    var index = Array.from(parent.children).indexOf(this);
    if (parent.children[index + 4]) {
      $(parent.children[index + 4]).addClass('hovered');
    } else if (parent.children[index - 4]) {
      $(parent.children[index - 4]).addClass('hovered');
    }

  }, function() {
    $('td').removeClass('hovered');
  });

})
```

```css
.hovered {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colSpan='1' />
      <th colSpan='4'>15 year</th>
      <th colSpan='4'>30 year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colSpan='1' />
      <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
      <th>Investment Payment</th>
      <th>Loan Amount</th>
      <th>Investment Amount</th>
      <th>Mortgage Payment</th>
      <th>Investment Payment</th>
      <th>Loan Amount</th>
      <th>Investment Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Year x</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Year x</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to add similar classes for both your tables. For example your `Year 4` `Mortage Payement` will have `year-4-mortage` class for both your 15 and your 30 years tables. Then you can use a simple jQuery to add an `active` class to the hovered elements which will have your desired css.

```
$('td').hover(function(){
   // Remove the current active class
   $('td').removeClass('active');

   //Add class to desired td
   $('.'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.active {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a solution myself as well. The function will fire `onMouseOver` in the `tr` element, but we could put it in the `tbody` as well, or really anywhere in the table.

```
const hoverTableCells = year => {
  // grab table cells depending on year
  const tableCells = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].children[year].children
  )

  const hover = (color, cell, index) => {
    const nextCells = tableCells[index + 4]
    const prevCells = tableCells[index - 4]

    cell.style.backgroundColor = color

    if (typeof nextCells !== 'undefined') {
      nextCells.style.backgroundColor = color
    }
    if (typeof prevCells !== 'undefined') {
      prevCells.style.backgroundColor = color
    }
  }

  // iterate over all cells in row and set appropriate color depending on mouse event
  tableCells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    cell.addEventListener('mouseover', () => hover('grey', cell, index))
    cell.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => hover('white', cell, index))
  })
}
```

I also added logic to make sure that the `Year` column isn't selected, but that wasn't part of my original question so I won't be including that in this answer.